# Orbit Download Manager massive send packets (no torrent)

Tags: wireshark, download-manager, spyware, internet-speed

recently I've noticed my internet connection speed is low even my modem console was opening very slow , after troubleshooting using Wireshark I've found massive packets send to "**sg.ilovewebgame.co.kr**" i've found out **orbit download manager** is sending these packets , I'm using orbit for long time and many computers and I trust it but can't find out what is the problem , I have updated **avast antivirus** and **malwarebytes** but they don't find any virus or spyware .

here is the captured packet :

> POST /member/login HTTP/1.1
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Referer: http://ssd.ilovewebgame.co.kr/member/login
>
> Host: sg.ilovewebgame.co.kr
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)

i found nothing on google about this site, How can i find out what is wrong with my orbit without reinstalling it ?

Comment: Avast and MalwareBytes might not be catching it, but that url and this behavior sounds **extremely** suspicious. I would recommend killing the process at minimum until you can figure out what it's doing or why it's visiting a Korean website. Keep an eye on network activity in case another process starts to behave similarly.

Comment: i'm no more let orbit execute and blocked it using comodo , but there is something interesting in orbitdm.exe , it has digital signature that belong to "KORAM GAMES LIMITED" , that have website similar to above url,link is [Koram Games](http://http://www.koramgame.com/en/), i'm continuing to find more information

Answer (score 0):

I notice orbit downloader is sending DNS queries for this domain's subdomains at 3Mbps. Orbit has turned into a malicious software. My recommendation is to ditch it for good...

**It has been confirmed that Orbit Downloader comes with a DDoS client that turns your computer into part of a botnet. Do not use Orbit Downloader!!**